# Maintaining Session from child (iframe) to parent page

Tags: php, mysql, session

here is my problem.

I invoke a form from a page with a iframe. 
After, i submit this form (the action is to redirect the parent page to another). Because of that, i lost my session (value) that I create in my child page.

I dont put my code because it's too big.

What can I do to maintain all my session value.

Thanks

This is my child window...

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $num = $_POST["num"];

    require('connexionClass.php');
    $connexion = new Connexion();
    $con = $connexion->open();
        if($con){
            mysql_select_db("test",$con);

                //RECUPERATION DES INFORMATIONS DU PATIENT
                $result = mysql_query("
                        SELECT *
                        FROM `patient` , `personne` , `adresse` , `telpers` , `telephone`
                        WHERE `Personne`.`idPersonne` = (
                            SELECT `idPersonne`
                            FROM `patient`
                            WHERE `numDossier` = '$num' )
                        AND `patient`.`idPersonne` = `Personne`.`idPersonne`
                        AND `telpers`.`idPersonne` = `Personne`.`idPersonne`
                        AND `adresse`.`idAdresse` = `Personne`.`idPersonne`
                        AND `telpers`.`idTel` = `Telephone`.`idTel`
                        ");
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                            if($row > 0){
                                $_SESSION["pName"] = $row["nom"];
                                $_SESSION["pPre"] = $row["prenom"];
                                $_SESSION["pSexe"] = $row["sexe"];
                                $_SESSION["pAnniv"] = $row["anniv"];
                                $_SESSION["pAssurance"] = $row["assurance"];
                                $_SESSION["pNumDossier"] = $row["numDossier"];
                                $_SESSION["pIdPersonne"] = $row["idPersonne"];
                                $_SESSION["pIdPatient"] = $row['ind']."-".$row["quartier"]."-".$row["num"];
                                $_SESSION["pIdAdresse"] = $row['idAdresse'];        
                                $_SESSION["pNum"] = $row["numRue"];
                                $_SESSION["pRue"] = $row["rue"];
                                $_SESSION["pVille"] = $row["ville"];
                                $_SESSION["pIdTel"] = $row["idTel"];
                                $_SESSION["ptypeTel"] = $row["typeTel"];
                                $_SESSION["pTel"] = $row['ind']."-".$row["quartier"]."-".$row["num"];
                            }
                        }//WHILE


                        $query = ("
                            SELECT COUNT(*)
                            FROM `patient` , `personne` , `adresse` , `telpers` , `telephone`
                            WHERE `Personne`.`idPersonne` = (
                                SELECT `idPersonne`
                                FROM `patient`
                                WHERE `numDossier` = '$num' )
                            AND `patient`.`idPersonne` = `Personne`.`idPersonne`
                            AND `telpers`.`idPersonne` = `Personne`.`idPersonne`
                            AND `adresse`.`idAdresse` = `Personne`.`idPersonne`
                            AND `telpers`.`idTel` = `Telephone`.`idTel`
                            ");
                        $results = mysql_query($query);
                        $values = mysql_fetch_assoc($results);
                        if($values["COUNT(*)"] ==1){
                            echo "<script> alert('Patient trouvé'); </script>";
?>
                        <html>
                            <head>
                                <style>
                                    #kform{
                                        width: 93.25%;
                                        background: white;
                                        padding: 10px 0 10px 5px;
                                        margin: -2% 5% 0 3.5%;
                                    }
                                    .lab{   float:left;  width: 30%;  margin-bottom: 5px;  }    
                                    .input{ margin-bottom: 5px; }
                                </style>
                                <script>
                                    function redirect(){
                                        window.parent.location = '../facture.php';
                                    }
                                </script>
                            </head>
                        <body>
                            <div  id = 'kform' class = 'hide'>
                                <form id = 'nonrep' name = 'nonrep' action = 'javascript:redirect();'>
                                    <div class = 'lab'> # du patient : </div>
                                    <div class = 'input'>  <input type = 'text' id = 'num' name = 'num' size = '14' value = '<?php echo $_SESSION["pNumDossier"]; ?>' readonly/> </div>
                                    <div class = 'lab'> Nom: </div>
                                    <div class = 'input'>  <input type = 'text' id = 'num' name = 'num' size = '14' value = '<?php echo $_SESSION["pName"]; ?>' readonly/> </div>
                                    <div class = 'lab'> Prenom: </div>
                                    <div class = 'input'>  <input type = 'text' id = 'num' name = 'num' size = '14' value = '<?php echo $_SESSION["pPre"]; ?>' readonly/> </div>
                                    <div class = 'lab'> Date de naissance: </div>
                                    <div class = 'input'>  <input type = 'text' id = 'num' name = 'num' size = '14' value = '<?php echo $_SESSION["pAnniv"]; ?>' readonly/> </div>
                                    <div class = 'lab'> Numero Civic: </div>
                                    <div class = 'input'>  <input type = 'text' id = 'num' name = 'num' size = '14' value = '<?php echo $_SESSION["pNum"]; ?>' readonly/> </div>
                                    <div class = 'lab'> Rue: </div>
                                    <div class = 'input'>  <input type = 'text' id = 'num' name = 'num' size = '14' value = '<?php echo $_SESSION["pRue"]; ?>' readonly/> </div>
                                    <div class = 'lab'> Ville: </div>
                                    <div class = 'input'>  <input type = 'text' id = 'num' name = 'num' size = '14' value = '<?php echo $_SESSION["pVille"]; ?>' readonly/> </div>
                                    <div class = 'lab'> Téléphone: </div>
                                    <div class = 'input'>  <input type = 'text' id = 'num' name = 'num' size = '14' value = '<?php echo $_SESSION["pTel"]; ?>' readonly/> </div>
                                    <input type = 'submit' value = 'Continuer' style= "margin-left: 280px;"/>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </body>
                        </html>
<?php                       
                        }//VALUES = 1 
                        else{                           
                            echo "<script> alert('Patient non trouvé'); </script>";
echo $query;
}                           
            $connexion->close($con);
        }//IF $CON
        else
            echo "<script> alert('No connection');</script>"; 
?>
```

My REDIRECT PAGE

```
<!-- Les etapes d'une facture
            1. CHOISIR LES MEDICAMENTS
            2. choisir le patient
            3. Confirmation de facture
-->
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .title{
                width: 90%;
                background-color: black;
                color: white;
                padding: 10px 0 10px 5px;
                margin: 0 5% 0 5%;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-align: center;
            }
            #kform{
                width: 90%;
                background: white;
                padding: 10px 0 10px 5px;
                margin: 0 5% 0 5%;
            }
            .gauche{float:left;}
            .body{ width: 750px; background-color: #F2F2F2; }
            #corps{ width: 100%;   }
            .nom{  width: 50%;  }
            .qte{ width: 15%; }
            .prix{ width: 15%; padding-left: 10px;}
            .bNom{  width: 45%; text-align: center; }
            .bQte{ width: 6%; text-align:center; margin-left: 3%; margin-right: 12%; }
            .bPrix{ width: 9%; text-align:center; margin-right: 4%; }
            .medic{ margin: 10px 0 10px 10px;}
            .barTitle{margin: 10px 0 20px 10px;}
            .total{ width:70%; text-align:right; margin-right: 50px; float:left;}
            .tot{ width:20%; float:left;}
        </style>
        <script>
            function redirect(){ window.location = 'patient.php'; }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class = "body">
            <!-- Including the menu -->
            <?php 
                include('menu.php'); 
                require('progressB.php');    
            ?>
            <div id = 'Index'> Commande > Etape # 3: Facture </div>

<?php       
            $progress = new Progress();
            $progress->progressBar(100);                    
?>
            <div id = "corps">
                <div class = 'title'> Facture </div>
                    <div  id = 'kform'>
                        <div class = 'barTitle'>
                            <div class = 'bNom gauche'><b>Nom</b></div>
                            <div class = 'bQte gauche'><b>Qté</b></div>
                            <div class = 'bPrix gauche'><b>Prix Un.</b></div>
                            <div class = 'bAction'><b>Total</b></div>
                        </div>
<?php
    $connexion = new Connexion();
    $con = $connexion->open();
    if($con){
        mysql_select_db("test",$con);
        $query = "
                SELECT *, `panier`.`qte`
                FROM `panier` , `produit`
                WHERE `panier`.`idPanier` = (
                            SELECT `idPanier`
                            FROM `specialiste`
                            WHERE `login` = '".$_SESSION["login"]."'
                                )
                AND `produit`.`idProduit` = `panier`.`idProduit`
            ";
            $j = 0;
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            if(!$result || mysql_num_rows($result)==0){ 
                echo "Vous n'avez pas d'article dans votre panier";
                echo "<input type = 'button' value = 'Continuer' style= 'margin-left: 280px;' onClick = 'javascript:redirect();' disabled/>";
            }
            else{
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                        $_SESSION["total$j"] = $row["qte"] * $row["prix"];
                        echo "<div class = 'medic'>
                                <div id = 'nom$j' class = 'nom gauche'>".$row["nom"]."</div>
                                <div id = 'qte$j'   class = 'qte gauche'>".$row["qte"]."</div>
                                <div id = 'prix$j'  class = 'prix gauche'>".$row["prix"]." $</div>
                                <div id = 'img$j ' class = 'supprimer'>".$_SESSION["total$j"]." $</div>
                                <input type='hidden' id = 'id$j' value = '".$row["idProduit"]."'/>
                              </div>";
                        $j++;
                    }//WHILE
                    echo "<div id = 'prix'  class = 'total'>SOUS-TOTAL </div>";

                    //CALCUL DU PRIX TOTAL SANS LES ASSURANCES
                    $prix = 0;
                    for($i = 0; $i < $j; $i++){
                        $prix = $prix + $_SESSION["total$i"];}

                    $_SESSION["totalFact"] = $prix;
                    echo "<div id = 'img$j ' class = 'tot'>".$_SESSION["totalFact"]." $</div>";

                    $query = "SELECT `patient`.`assurance` FROM `patient`,`personne` WHERE `patient`.`idPersonne` = ( SELECT `idPersonne` FROM `personne` WHERE `personne`.`nom` = '".$_SESSION["pName"]."' ) AND `patient`.`idPersonne` = `personne`.`idPersonne`";
                    echo $query;
                    $result = mysql_query($query);
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ echo $row["assurance"]; }
                    echo "<div class='assurance'>".$_SESSION["pAssurance"]."</div>";
            }//ELSE
            echo "<input type = 'button' value = 'Continuer' style= 'margin-left: 280px;' onClick = 'javascript:redirect();'/>";
    }//$CON
    $connexion->close($con);  //CLOSE CONNECTION
?>
                    </div>
                </div>          
            <!-- Including the footer -->
            <?php include('footer.php'); ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My error

```
Notice: Undefined index: pName in C:\Server\www\medical-clinic\facture.php on line 108

Notice: Undefined index: pAssurance in C:\Server\www\medical-clinic\facture.php on line 112
```

Comment: Lost how? A child iframe can set a cookie just as well as a top level window.

Comment: I try to retake it and it says it is undefined

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `session_start()` call in that code block. Unless you start the session, any data you write to the $_SESSION superglobal will NOT be preserved for you when the script exits.

Comment: yes I have. I have it in my parent page, my child page and my redirect page